# getting variable from session doesn't work

Tags: php, session, global

In my login-script I start a session and put a username in. But with my code in another script I can't get the variable back.

```
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$conn = mysqli_connect("#", "#", "#", "#");
$query = "SELECT username, password from login where username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->fetch())
{
  $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
  header("Location: site.php");
  exit();
}
```

P.S.: I don't know why I am sometimes using mySQLi and sometimes PDO.

```
include "login.php";
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: it appears that you are not hashing the user's password in the database - use `password_hash` and `password_verify` to correctly store and use passwords. Is it possible that the sql query is failing and NOT populating the session variable - the above code doesn't look like there are any problems as such apart from failing to check if the `$stmt` is being created or testing the return value of `execute`

Comment: If redirection is working, then $stmt is fine. If this is the case, you must be sure that you use session_start() before use $_SESSION['login_user'].

Comment: Redirection works... I have a Index file wich includes the login script. And the username is needed to check if the user has permission (get permission where username = $username). Is there an other way, for saving the username and get it in another file?

Comment: Oh, I found the mistake... I didn't start the session at the top of the page...